# Soulseek port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I did port forwarding for Soulseek. If I click "Check ports" now, it says the ports are open (before it didn't), but I still get these error messages:

> Requesting file list...
>
> A connection could not be successfully formed to the user. If this is happening to you a lot, Check here to make sure that your port is open.

And yes, I did a restart. Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour?